# Should the [majority] and [supermajority] tags be "burninated"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Should the [majority](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/majority) and [supermajority](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supermajority) tags be "burninated"?

- [majority](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/majority) (8 questions tagged; 877 questions using the term)
- [supermajority](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supermajority) (2 questions tagged; 26 questions using the term)

Both terms seem too general to be of value as tags. They may apply to elections and referenda, passage of legislation, composition of a legislature, demographics, etc., even "age of majority" and, in some cases, "majority" is the margin of the winner in an plurality election.

Whatever "majority" may be *about* is dependent on its context in the question. The same applies to "supermajority".

One question: [How true is it that people vote for parties/people that benefit their stances most? Then does majority rule offer "best outcomes"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/31333/26455), uses [majority](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/majority) as its only tag, but the question appears to be about, and may be sufficiently tagged as, [democracy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/democracy) and [political-theory](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-theory).

Comment: *supermajority* seems to be a highly specific concept in legislative assemblies, constitutional amendments or or the like and a dedicated tag seems helpful to differentiate contexts where it is applicable.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - Following are counts and search terms: 26 `is:q supermajority`, 37 `is:q vot* "two-thirds" -supermajority`, 25 `is:q vot* "2/3" -"two-thirds" -supermajority`. Most questions that mention supermajority voting do not use the term. Though *supermajority* is a significant concept, the term, apparently, is not that important for most such questions. One other problem is the number of questions that have five tags. In those cases, a [supermajority] tag likely would be the least important tag and should not replace an existing tag.